# AS3: gotoAndPlay not working

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, goto

I'm trying to gotoAndPlay using AS3 in a certain frame inside a symbol, my target frame is inside another symbol which is **"Carrera"** (class name). Both symbols where placed on the scene by dragging from the library.

**I've tried with:**

```
MovieClip(carrera).gotoAndPlay(1);
```

**Error Output:**

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert carrera$ to flash.display.MovieClip.
    at fondoUcreativa/frame500()
```

**Also tried with:**

```
carrera.gotoAndPlay(1);
```

**Compiler Error:**

```
Symbol 'fondo Ucreativa', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 500, Line 4    1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay through a reference with static type Class.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the method "gotoAndPlay" your Carrera class must extends MovieClip.

Comment: Is Carrera a class defined by code or is something you've in your library?

Comment: Asigned using library properties. "Linkage"

Comment: And when you assigned it the linkage, did you define Movie Clip as "base class"?

Comment: Where can I do that? I placed the object on the scene by dragging it.

Comment: Right click the object in your library and select Properties. Check in the linkage section if in the base class you have "flash.display.MovieClip". If it already like this (and I supposed it is, because is the default setting when you select "export for actionscript"), then the problem is another. It could be that you're dragging the instance on the stage and you're not assigning it a instance name.

Comment: You were right, I wasn't making the linkage for the symbol on the stage, I was only doing it for the library.`Carrera.gotoAndPlay(1);` didn't work, but `MovieClip(root).Carrera.gotoAndPlay(1);` did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself. `carrera` is a Class, not an instance. Hence, you can not access `carrera.gotoAndPlay()` which is an instance method, not a static method.

You're going to have to name the instance of that class (say `carreraInst`), from the properties panel

Then you can call it as `carreraInst.gotoAndPlay(1);`

On a somewhat off-topic note, class names, by convention, begin with an upper case letter, so it should have been `Carrera` instead of `carrera`

Comment: Didn't work. `CarreraIns.gotoAndPlay(1);`Gives the following error `Symbol 'fondo Ucreativa', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 500, Line 3 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndPlay through a reference with static type Class.
` I double checked the class name.